# Trigger - inserting default values into primary key when missing data

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, null

I have problem with creating triggers to table.

```
create table dwarfs (
name varchar2(20),
nickname varchar2(20),
note varchar2(20),
primary key (name,nickname)
);
```

Idea:
When someone want to insert data without entering name trigger should add default name for example "Dwarf1"

I created trigger but I get

```
communicate:SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"

create or replace trigger t_d
before insert or update on dwarfs
for each row
when (new.name=null or new.name= '')
declare
begin
:new.name:='Dwarf1';
end;
```

Comment: What nickname are you trying to insert? All columns of a primary key must not be null

Comment: Tip: use `new.name is null` instead of `(new.name=null or new.name= '')`. But there is another problem - primary key is unique, and you can't insert the same value twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kodirko noted in his comment, the comparison `(new.name=null or new.name='')` will never work, because a comparison with NULL always returns NULL, not TRUE or FALSE. To determine if a column is NULL you need to use the special comparison construct `IS NULL`. Also note that because `nickname` is part of the primary key it also must never be NULL - so, when taken all together you might try rewriting your trigger as:

```
create or replace trigger t_d
  before insert or update on dwarfs
  for each row
  when (new.name IS NULL OR NEW.NICKNAME IS NULL)
begin
  IF :new.NAME IS NULL THEN
    :new.NAME := 'Dwarf1';
  END IF;

  IF :new.NICKNAME IS NULL THEN
    :new.NICKNAME := :new.NAME;
  END IF;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case of not seeing the forest for the trees. Yes, there is the technical detail of using `=` in a test for `null`. The main point, however is...

<kbd>NEVER, EVER ASSIGN DEFAULT VALUES TO KEY FIELDS!!!</kbd>

If a field is a key field, the tuple is explicitly unusable without it. If that data is missing, there is something very, very wrong and the remainder of the row should be prevented at all costs from being inserted into the database.

This does not, of course, apply to an Identity or auto generating value that is defined as the surrogate key. Surrogate keys are, by definition, completely independent of the entity data. (This points out a disadvantage of surrogate keys, but that is a different discussion.) This applies only to attribute fields that have been further identified as key fields.

If the value is missing and a default value is not supplied, any attempt to insert the row will generate an error. Which is exactly what you want to happen. Don't make it easy for the users to destroy the integrity of the database.

Comment: that's not completely true. if you use a "select seq.nextval" as the default value...